# Find the smallest $3$ digit number when divided by $7$ given the following conditions?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

[image]

**My Approach**

I could solve the problem till this.

Numbers are given of the form $7k+3$ and $6k+5$, so I took $\text{lcm}(7,5)k-4=35k-4$.  To be the smallest number $35k- 4 \leq 100 = 35k < 104$.

$\Rightarrow k< \frac{104}{35} \Rightarrow k=2$.

But I am not getting to any $3$ digit number.

Comment: Use Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: 101 is answer and basically for such sums you directly do the calculations or use chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: Obviously the only one of those four choices that has a remainder of 1 when divided by 5 is 101. Then you can easily check that it satisfies the other two conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ leaves a remainder of $3$ when divided by $7$, a remainder of $1$ when divided by $5$, and a remainder of $5$ when divided by $6$, then $x$ must satisfy the system of congruences 
\begin{align*}
x & \equiv 3 \pmod{7} \tag{1}\\
x & \equiv 1 \pmod{5} \tag{2}\\
x & \equiv 5 \pmod{6} \tag{3}
\end{align*}
The first congruence implies $x = 7k + 3$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Substituting $7k + 3$ into the second congruence yields 
$$7k + 3 \equiv 1 \pmod{5} \Rightarrow x = 5(7k + 3) + 1 = 35k + 16$$
Substituting $35k + 16$ into the third congruence yields
$$35k + 16 \equiv 5 \pmod{6} \Rightarrow x = 6(35k + 16) + 5 = 210k + 101$$
The smallest three-digit integer of this form is $101$.

Comment: How can you substitute the value of x=$7k$+$3$ in $5l$+$3$.

Comment: @justintakro  I rewrote my answer in terms of congruences.  I hope this clarifies what I did earlier.  If you are not familiar with congruences, $x \equiv y \pmod{n}$ if there exists an integer $k$ such that $x - y = kn$, that is, if $x$ and $y$ have the same remainder when divided by $n$.